# how to load image from camera for specific/variable sizes?

Tags: ios, image, uiimage

I have a very simple requirement here but I'm looking for a solution for a while. I want to take a profile picture form the camera roll or camera and display it in two different image views (different sizes). I don't want any of these images stretched or miss any part of the image. If I use aspect to fit, top side of image is cut from smaller image view and some parts missing on the bigger image view. If I set it as scale to fit, it will get stretched!

I'm not sure how some mobile apps work. Do they save different image sizes in their server or they change the size of the image. I saw many posts how to change image size without changing aspect ratio. But I don't think it is possible to avoid stretched effects. I used some of those code to change size of image, it gets stretched all the time.

Is there any way to save the image from camera roll one time with size of 140*200 and one time 160*200? So I can use 140*200 for image views that size. But what if I have different devices and different sizes.

[image]

Comment: Use scall to fit to imageview

Comment: if I use scall to fit it will change the image and make it stretched

Comment: then use size to fit